# ONNX Runtime: io_binding.bind_input causing "no data transfer from DeviceType:1 to DeviceType:0"

Tags: pytorch, onnx, tritonserver

I am using Nvidia Triton Inference Server and ONNX model for inference on a GPU instance.
The Dockerfile, containing the environment, inference server and models contains following `from/pip` lines:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:23.12-py3

RUN pip install torch transformers onnx onnxruntime-gpu onnxruntime
```

the `model.py` for the Triton Inference Server has been simplified to following:

```py
import onnxruntime as ort
import torch
import numpy as np

session = ort.InferenceSession("path/to/onnx.model", providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider", "CPUExecutionProvider"])

...

io_binding = session.io_binding()
pt_script_embeddings = torch.rand(
    size=(100, 2010), dtype=torch.float32, device="cuda:0"
).contiguous()

io_binding.bind_input(
    name="np_script_embeddings",
    device_type="cuda",
    device_id=0,
    element_type=np.float32,
    shape=tuple(pt_script_embeddings.shape),
    buffer_ptr=pt_script_embeddings.data_ptr(),
)

logit_output_shape = (100, 2)
logit_output = torch.empty(logit_output_shape, dtype=torch.float32, device='cuda:0').contiguous()
io_binding.bind_output(
    name="np_logits",
    device_type="cuda",
    device_id=0,
    element_type=np.float32,
    shape=tuple(logit_output.shape),
    buffer_ptr=logit_output.data_ptr()
)

session.run_with_iobinding(io_binding)
outputs = logit_output.cpu().numpy()
```

Unfortunately, the error below is triggered at the line `io_binding.bind_input` causing me a lot of grief:

```
RuntimeError: Error when binding input: There's no data transfer registered for copying tensors from Device:[DeviceType:1 MemoryType:0 DeviceId:0] to Device:[DeviceType:0 MemoryType:0 DeviceId:0]
```

Note: articles reviewed before the SO submission:

- https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/10286
- https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/10327
- https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/python/api_summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I needed to carefully match versions of`cuda`, `pytorch` and `onnxruntime` provided by the `tritonserver` docker image with the Python packages of `torch` and `onnxruntime-gpu` installed manually. Here is the process in details:

- Understand what version of CUDA is currently supported by the `onnxruntime-gpu` by visiting [onnx cuda execution provider](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements). In my case it was `cuda==12.2`
- Navigate to the [Triton IS release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/triton-inference-server/release-notes/rel-24-01.html#rel-24-01) and look for the `Container Version` with the matching cuda version from prior step. In my case it was `tritonserver:23.10-py3`
- Navigate to the [Triton IS version matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/support-matrix/index.html) to retrieve the version of PyTorch included with the Triton IS Docker Image. In my case `torch 2.1`

Base on the collected versions, update the environment. In my case it is the Docker image with following changes:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:23.10-py3

RUN pip install transformers
RUN pip install torch==2.1

# https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/install/
# https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html#requirements
RUN pip install onnxruntime-gpu --extra-index-url https://aiinfra.pkgs.visualstudio.com/PublicPackages/_packaging/onnxruntime-cuda-12/pypi/simple/
```

NOTE: if your build environment has no access to the Azure repo: https://aiinfra.pkgs.visualstudio.com/PublicPackages/_packaging/onnxruntime-cuda-12/pypi/simple/  then retrieve and install the files manually from: https://aiinfra.visualstudio.com/PublicPackages/_artifacts/feed/onnxruntime-cuda-12 (make sure to correct `cuda-12` for your version)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely just an installation issue.

The error you are getting

```
There's no data transfer registered for copying tensors from DeviceType:1 to DeviceType:0
```

means that `ort` is trying to copy data from the GPU (`DeviceType:1`, the torch tensor you explicitly initialized on `cuda:0`) to the CPU (`DeviceType:0`, the `InferenceSession`).

As 1) this transfer should be possible and 2) the `InferenceSession` should be on the GPU in the first place, what is probably happening is that your redundant installation of `onnxruntime` *after* `onnxruntime-gpu` in Dockerfile is messing up the dependencies. I.e. your code is using the `onnxruntime` installation which does not have GPU support.

Add `print(session.get_providers())` to confirm that your session is defaulting to just `CPUExecutionProvider`, and try rebuilding the container without the unnecessary library installation.